# How can a stackview dynamically change the spacing between the elements nested inside of it

Tags: swift, xcode, autolayout, uistackview

For months now I have been trying to wrap my head around stackviews and how they work. For that reason I have created a project which has 4 buttons nested inside of a stack view with constant width and height. Now depending on the iPhone screen size, I want the buttons inside of the stackview to maintain their width and size, but the spacing between them to get smaller or bigger. This is done perfectly if I manually adjust the stackview size using my mouse. But, the moment I add top and bottom constraints which should have the same effect, the buttons inside of the stack view shrinks or weirdly stretched even if they all have constant height with the priority set to 1000.

You can try it for yourself by creating a stack view with some buttons inside of it and then set their width and height constant. Afterwards add top and bottom constraints and preview it on a smaller screen size than the one you are creating it.

Preview on an iPhone XS and if the screen is smaller the gap between the buttons should dynamically change to being bigger or smaller:

[image]

Preview on an iPhone 8:

[image]

And how it should look like:

[image]

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening and how I can achieve the result I want?

Comment: what you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of adding a bottom constraint you should only add height constraint to `UIStackView`, checkout following example

```
let buttons = [UIButton(), UIButton(), UIButton(), UIButton()]
for (index, button) in buttons.enumerated() {
    button.backgroundColor = .red
    button.setTitle("Category Button \(index)", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
}
let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: buttons)
stackView.axis = .vertical
stackView.distribution = .equalSpacing
stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.view.addSubview(stackView)

let salGuide = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: salGuide.topAnchor, constant: 16.0),
    stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: salGuide.centerXAnchor, constant: 0),
    stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: salGuide.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.6),
    stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: salGuide.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.6)
])
```

Note that `multiplier: 0.6` gives 60% of available width and height to `UIStackView`, to use constant width/height just change parameter name from `multiplier` to `constant` and provide appropriate parameter value.

**iPhone SE**

[image]

**iPhone Xs Max**

[image]